# read_csv - не получается корректно прочитать csv -файл

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv("./gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Airplane_Crashes_and_Fatalities_Since_1908[1].csv", names = ['Date','Time','Location','Operator','Flight#','Route','Type','Registration','cn/In','Aboard','Fatalities','Ground','Summary'], usecols=range(0, 13))
```

После такого кода выдается таблица такого рода [image: .] в csv-файле есть запятые внутри кавычек( внутри одного значения) - как можно корректно [прочитать файл?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATPQt.png)

Comment: Добавьте пример csv (прямо в вопрос, кнопка `править`)

Comment: Судя по результату это у вас не CSV файл, а HTML